# what is the different between struct stat * buffer and &buffer in linux stat function

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to get the parent directory stats.

If I wrtie code like below it return `error: Bad address`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(int agrc, char * argv[]){
    struct stat *buffer;
    int res = stat("..", buffer);
    if(res != 0){
        perror("error");
        exit(1);
    }
    //printf("%d", buffer->st_ino);

}
```

But If I write code like this below, there is no problem.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(int agrc, char * argv[]){
    /* struct stat *buffer; */
    struct stat buffer;
    int res = stat("..", &buffer);
    if(res != 0){
        perror("error");
        exit(1);
    }
    //printf("%d", buffer->st_ino);
    printf("%d", buffer.st_ino);

}
```

I do not know why the result is different.

The variable `buffer` of definition `struct stat * buffer` is a pointer of `struct stat`

The `&buffer` is also a pointer of `struct stat`

The function is defined as below in manpage

```sh
SYNOPSIS
       #include <sys/types.h>
       #include <sys/stat.h>
       #include <unistd.h>

       int stat(const char *pathname, struct stat *buf);
       ...
```

I expected the result to be both successful, why the result is different? anyone can help, thanks a lot.

Comment: `struct something *x;` without initialization is almost always suspicious, but passing it to a function is certainly an error. There is no way for the function to sanitize an invalid pointer, so if you haven't set it to `NULL` explicitly it's definitely a mistake. And if you enabled all warnings on your compiler, you would have avoided this problem in the first place: [this is what gcc returns with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`](https://godbolt.org/z/tOSGIi).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `struct stat buffer;` , there is memory allocated for `buffer` on the stack.
But with  `struct stat *buffer;` there is no memory allocated for `buffer`. You have to use a memory allocation function to allocate memory. This allocation happens on what is known as heap.

```
struct stat *buffer = malloc(sizeof(struct stat));
```

Note that [**`stat()`**](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) stats the file pointed to by `path` and fills in `buf`. So if `buf` does not point to memory that the program owns, it will result in `error: Bad address`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I got it.
The `struct stat buffer` will automatically allocate memory,
but `struct stat *buffer` will only define a pointer variable, without pointing to any memory.